# Entity Linq find index before query is executed

Tags: c#, linq, entity

I have the following query:

```
var result = //some Entity framework IOrderedQueryable;
var fullList = await result.ToListAsync();
var currentIndex = fullList.FindIndex(x => x.Id== model.Id);
var nextRecord = fullList[currentIndex + 1];
```

This code works and does what I need.

The problem is, if the full list is thousands of entries, I have to pull the whole thing into memory to find the one item I am looking for.

Is there a more efficient way I can achieve this?

As a note, there are some dynamic where clauses applied to the Queryable, so it has to be done like this, rather than, for example, writing in SQL

Comment: Create a dictionary : Dictionary<string, int> dict = fullList.Select((x,i) => new { id = x.Id, index = i})
   .GroupBy(x => x.Id, y => y.index)
   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

Comment: Alex, are you asking if it's possible to check the data without the data?

Comment: @uTeisT I apologize for my confusion, but I cannot work out if you are being sarcastic or not?

Comment: @uTeisT I am asking if there is  a way to write an intelligent query to obtain this information